# FabricException in service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to learn service fabric in Visual Studio 2015 from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/tree/vs2015). 
`WebService` is set as a startup project and is `Single startup project` in properties of the `solution`.

When I run the project I get

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Fabric.FabricException' occurred in WebService.exe
```

at [line 39](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/blob/vs2015/src/GettingStartedApplication/WebService/Program.cs#L39).

When I stop debugging the `Output` window shows:

```
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\shkulka\Downloads\GettingStartedApplication\WebService\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\WebService.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Fabric\v4.0_5.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Fabric.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\shkulka\Downloads\GettingStartedApplication\WebService\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\shkulka\Downloads\GettingStartedApplication\WebService\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x64\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Internal.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Fabric.Strings\v4.0_5.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Fabric.Strings.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in System.Fabric.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Fabric.FabricException' in WebService.exe
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'WebService.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WebService.exe): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[18428] WebService.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18428] WebService.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

How do I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Event Viewer can provide some insights about service fabric errors.

Comment: @xaero99: Thanks, I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 'GettingStartedApplication' as your startup project instead.